# Tableview Rows delete ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I used two(canEditRowAtIndexPath and commitEditingStyle ) methods for delete rows based on index, whenever I went to next view and coming back to the table view deleted rows are again appeared.
How can I delete the rows permanently in table view? it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: You need to update your data source, I mean your array of objects that you are showing in your tableView

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just delete the data from UI, so you got the problem.

You must delete the data from your source and UI at the same time.

Just reference this code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property UITableView* tableView;
@property NSMutableArray* dataArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        [_dataArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test%d",i]];
    }

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];

    _tableView.editing = true;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _dataArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return true;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //Delete data from source
        [_dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //Delete row from UI
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}

@end
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `NSMutableArray` as your `UITableView's` datasource.
2. In `commitEditingStyle` Delegate....

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
          if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
              [datasourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          }
   }
   ```